# Which one is true IP address of my laptop running Windows?

Tags: windows, ipconfig

I have Windows 10 laptop and connected to office Wi-Fo. I am not able to SSH to my company’s AWS EC2 instance so admin asked me the IP address of my laptop.

I did `ipconfig` and it returned me two ipv4 addresses.

- Default switch - Autoconfiguraton IPv4 address = `169.254.10.128`
- Wireless LAN IPv4 address = `139.49.123.210`

Which IP should I give to him?

Comment: you should of course ask that question to your admin! Thats his job! Alternatively if you dont want to ask things like that, just dump him your whole console output under the pretence to provide him with as much info as possible so he can fix your problem faster ;)

Answer (score 3):

`139.49.123.210` is your IP address.

`169.254.10.128` is a non routable IP.

As explained in the IETF’s “[Special Use IPv4 Addresses](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5735.txt)”:

> 169.254.0.0/16 - This is the "link local" block. As described in [RFC3927], it is allocated for communication between hosts on a single link. Hosts obtain these addresses by auto-configuration, such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

As [yagmoth555 answered](https://superuser.com/a/1349029/85791) most likely 139.49.123.210, but
depending on how you're effectively connected to the internet neither IP-address may be what needs to be whitelisted.

If there is [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) the effective IP-address won't show with `ipconfig`.

Also check what ip-address appears as your public IP-address with  a *"what's my ip-address"* online service such as for instance  https://ipconfig.io

Answer (score 0):

when you type `ipconfig` you will get number of list for the ip address.

check for the

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
```

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

here IPv4 Address line contains your ip.

Comment: That's the local IP address. You can't access the PC from outside the network with that. See [What is the difference between 127.0.0.1 and my assigned IPv4 address?](https://superuser.com/q/897699/241386)